# Using the LaunchImage and AppIcon inside the iOS app

Tags: uiimage, icons, launch-screen, launchimage, uiimageasset

I have images.acassets in my XCode project. I have set AppIcon source and Launch Image source properly. Everything works perfect. I am able to see the launch image correctly once the app is launched. Can I use this same launch Image inside the app in different xib, where I would like to set this image as background image for one of the xib. When I select the imageview from xib and click on image in the right panel, I am not able to see the image listed in the all image list. Any idea??